# Index of unique values in df.column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv data set with a currency column. I need to clean the duplicates.

In :

```
df1=df.currency.unique()
print(df1)
```

Out :

```
['INR' 'USD' 'INR\n' 'USD\n']
```

I want to get rid of the rows containing strictly 'INR' and 'USD' and keep 'INR\n' and'USD\n'. I tried many things that didn't work for example:

```
df1 = df[df.index.str.contains('USD')]
```

But it mixes 'USD' and 'USD\n' and that's precisely what I want to avoid. Please advise.

Here is a sample of the datas :

```
      product_code customer_code market_code  order_date  sales_qty  \
0           Prod001        Cus001     Mark001  2017-10-10        100   
2           Prod002        Cus003     Mark003  2018-04-06          1   
3           Prod002        Cus003     Mark003  2018-04-11          1   
4           Prod002        Cus004     Mark003  2018-06-18          6   
5           Prod003        Cus005     Mark004  2017-11-20         59   
...             ...           ...         ...         ...        ...   
150278      Prod339        Cus005     Mark004  2019-04-18          1   
150279      Prod339        Cus020     Mark004  2019-04-23          1   
150280      Prod339        Cus007     Mark004  2019-04-23          1   
150281      Prod339        Cus006     Mark004  2019-04-24          7   
150282      Prod339        Cus032     Mark009  2019-04-24          3   

        sales_amount currency  
0            41241.0      INR  
2              875.0      INR  
3              583.0      INR  
4             7176.0      INR  
5              500.0      USD  
...              ...      ...  
150278         394.0    INR\n  
150279         667.0    INR\n  
150280         625.0    INR\n  
150281        8625.0    INR\n  
150282        3792.0    INR\n  

[150281 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Can you provide a clear sample dataset (as text of DataFrame constructor)?

Answer (score 1):

You could filter for '\n' like so:

```
df1 = df[df.currency.str.contains('\n')]
```

Comment: I get : "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"
'\n' is not a string it's an additional line within the row.

Comment: You most likely mean `df.currency.str.contains("\n")` instead of `df.index.str.contains('\n')`? Then it should work.

Comment: You could be more precise: `df[df.currency.str[-1].eq("\n")]`

Comment: df[df.currency.str[-1].eq("\n")] worked, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df1 = ['INR', 'USD', 'INR\n', 'USD\n']
>>> uniq_df1 = set([curr.strip() for curr in df1])
>>> uniq_df1
{'USD', 'INR'}
>>> # if you need it in a list:
>>> uniq_df1 = list(set([curr.strip() for curr in df1]))
>>> uniq_df1
['USD', 'INR']
```

You see that I haven't preserved the ones with `\n`, because this is not a good practice. A list of currencies is a list of `['USD', 'INR']`. This: `['USD\n', 'INR\n']`, is a list of currencies with new line. (*Of course, strictly speaking they're both lists of strings, but for pedagogical reasons I used the word currencies.*)

Leave the formating when printing, file-saving or anything else that needs a new line with the proper technique for it.

Comment: 'INR' and 'USD' are a small subset of duplicate, about 300 rows on 150K. I don't want to delete the 'USD\n', 'INR\n' rows otherwise my df is destroyed.
Beside I don't understand your code, I need to delete the rows containing 'INR' and 'USD' strictly. Not sure that's what it does?

Comment: Do you mean all the other currencies in your subset have the `\n` at the end? If the answer is yes, you should normalize your data set first.